# PHP Warning: date(): - thats all I get on IIS php 5.5.1

Tags: php, windows, apache, iis, timezone

OK, I've managed to install php and get it to run, but I use date(); in several scripts. First I got the error with the not set timezone, I've set the timezone like this:

date.timezone = “Europe/Berlin”

now I get this error:
PHP Warning:  date():  in blabla on line 13

no error message at all, why do I get this? It's really hard to google because of the other errors, also date, php and warning aren't the bes keywords. Here is my google search:

php Warning: date(): -"It is not safe to rely on" -"expects parameter"

It would be great if someone had a solution for the error or a suggestion for a google search.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: the script works on Xampp on the same machine

Edit 2:
So this is the actual line:

$uhrzeit = date("d.m.Y - H:i:s",$timestamp);

and here is the $timestamp set:
$timestamp = time();

Comment: Can you add the code please?

Comment: Added, thanks for looking at it

Comment: which server not work

Comment: Sorry I thought I added it, Windoes Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); 
Keep this in your page which runs every time like config file.

Comment: So there is no way to do this with the php.ini?

Comment: OK after I replaced " with ' and restarted it haven't worked, but after the 2. time it did. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
```

Comment: It works when I add date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); but it doesn't work with the php.ini that is strange?. Thanks for your reply I will use this if I can't find a solution.

Comment: Make sure you use the actual php.ini (some distributions add example .ini files), and restart IIS / PHP after you change the .ini file